# VPL doesn't calculate cube root

Tags: robotics-studio

I was trying to calculate cube root using VPL: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjng6fjf081ovkq/shot_140214_212725.png
What I'm doing is setting the value to the power of 1/3 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4f8eqep8rm3jpw0/shot_140214_212742.png 
And as a result it gives me 1 all the time. 
Where the problem could be? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet 1/3 is getting truncated to 0, because the numerator and denominator are both integers.
Any number raised to the 0 power gives 1.

If you use 1.0/3.0 instead, it might work.